# Synchronize IMAP to maildir folders - fast and complete solution with IDLE support?

Tags: command-line, software-rec, synchronization, imap, maildir

This is likely to be borderline subjective, but I am searching for good alternatives for command line IMAP to maildir clients: Currently I am using `offlineimap`, but the docs are lacking, and support is vaning, what is a good alternative to `offlineimap` that has `IDLE` support, is fast and mature (does not loose e-mails). Ideally it should synchronize maildir flags (and gmail labels, but can't get everything). I know of:

- offlineimap
- mbsync

Comment: Since you wrote gmailieer, can you tell me why you would like to use offlineimap instead for gmail? I am using offlineimap and notmuch too, but I'm having a lot of trouble with labels and deletion.

Comment: I wrote gmailieer after asking this question, starting the same day. I use it still.

Answer (score 0):

Nice solution is [gmailieer](https://github.com/gauteh/gmailieer/). It doesn't use IMAP but GMail API. Synchronize gmail labels with notmuch database. So it is useful only with [e-mail clients with notmuch support](https://notmuchmail.org/#index4h2t). Gmailieer itself do not have api permission to delete Your messages from GMail. So it depends what are Your needs and email client You're using.

Comment: Thanks, I am somewhat familiar with gmailieer myself ;)

Comment: Opps. Now I realized Gmailieer your project :D